# How to record trackBar last value and the current value find the different and assign to the labels all the numbers between last and current values?

Tags: c#, winforms

Including the last and the current values.
the current code is not changing the labels texts.

the goal is to capture the trackBar value/s no matter how fast I move the mouse left or right.

I tried with mouse up and down events but it's not doing much.
not sure how to make the calculation with the events.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sliders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Label[] tile = new Label[11];

        int oldValue = 0;
        int lastValue = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            oldValue = macTrackBar1.Value;

            for (int i = 0; i < tile.Length; i++)
            {
                tile[i] = new Label();
                tile[i].Height = 18;
                tile[i].Width = 10;
                tile[i].Left = 0;
                tile[i].Top = i * 20;
                tile[i].Text = i.ToString();
                tile[i].Visible = true;
                Controls.Add(tile[i]);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void macTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)
        {
            if(lastValue > oldValue)
            {
                int newValue = lastValue - oldValue;

                for(int i = 0; i < newValue; i++)
                {
                    tile[i].Text = i.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        private void macTrackBar1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lastValue = macTrackBar1.Value;
        }

        private void macTrackBar1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            oldValue = macTrackBar1.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `lastValue = macTrackBar1.Value;` to the macTrackBar1_ValueChanged event. Secondly the `private void macTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)`  Is not valid event handler i think you need to have it like `private void macTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```
 private void macTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, decimal value)
    {
        lastValue = macTrackBar1.Value;
        if(lastValue > oldValue)
        {
            
            int newValue = lastValue - oldValue;

            for(int i = 0; i < newValue; i++)
            {
                tile[i].Text = i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void macTrackBar1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void macTrackBar1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        oldValue = macTrackBar1.Value;
    }
```

The label is not changing because you put the same text to it. Always put the same index value to them.
try:

```
tile[i].Text = newValue.ToString();
```